# How do I continue to group all operations in the following code after group_by is grouped

Tags: r

```
a <- c("w","api","oc","fc","fc2","cov","OPEC")
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  
      daytime[[i]] = r_new %>% group_by((.[a[i]]))%>% select("r_daytime")
      
      daytime[[i]] <- as.matrix(as.numeric(unlist(daytime[[i]])))

      InSampleData  = daytime[[i]][1:3100]
      OutSampleData = daytime[[i]][3100:3853]

      Fit = UniGASFit(GASSpec, InSampleData)

      Forecast = UniGASFor(Fit, Roll = TRUE, out = OutSampleData)

      alpha = 0.05

      VaR = quantile(Forecast, alpha)

      BackTest = BacktestVaR(OutSampleData[[i]], VaR, alpha)
      print(BackTest)
}
```